# редактирование django admin panel

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

Можно как-то выводить какие-либо значения(нижний левый угол скрина +- на месте где красный тескт) без изменения шаблона админки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

надо переопределять шаблон админки, который именно для этого apps будет.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]